# How would I go about getting AJAX data *from* Rails and render it back in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

The project I've been working on has taken many shapes over the last few months, but its most recent incarnation was one which involved a RESTful Rails backend with React, Jade and Express on the frontend.  This worked fine since React and Jade handled any data rendering on the frontend, and it allowed us to break out the requests from one *monolithic* request to about three much, much tinier ones.

The mandate is now to merge the view components into Rails, and this...is where I'm stuck.

As I said before, the world was different - The RESTful Rails routes were on one side of the fence, and the client was on another, meaning that AJAX requests were the only game in town.  Here are some sample routes:

- v1/property/:field
- v1/property2/:field
- v1/property3/:field

All of these routes work independently of *any* UI, so for the purpose of this question, we should treat them as a data source.

These are all requested on a single dashboard-like page, with each request pertaining to a specific part of it, all backed by a search bar which allows one to insert a specific calendar date. I've got this visually working now in a single view (mind the polygons).

[image]

**My main concern is the request to each of the three other parts of the view.**  It is unclear to me how to have each of these independently make their requests to the appropriate RESTful route with the appropriate value provided by the search bar.

I've tried a hackish approach to this particular problem:

- Within the search module's JS file, on its submission, create a new event called `doingSearch`.
- Use this event to provide the information I received from the search module's `<input>` tag, falling back to its placeholder value if I don't have anything else.
- In `_property.js.erb`, I listen for this event and emit *two* AJAX requests:

  - The first request is to the endpoint, `v1/property/:field`, and if it is successful, the second request is a POST, which goes to a route /board/:field/handle_post. The belief here is that I have more control over this route, and can dictate what's rendered here.
- I then render `_property.html.erb` at the end of `_property.js.erb`, but I would rather like to pass the JSON data into `_property.html.erb` as if it were a Rails model for simplicity's sake.  If at all possible, the logical solution would be to render the view after the POST request had been submitted, but that's another sticking point - I'm unclear on how to approach that.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with data you will want to use the flux pattern. Here is an example from https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.14/ReFluxSuperAgent. The api.store handles the actions that initiate an ajax request. The util/api.js handles the ajax requests. The basic.store receives the data through actions from util/api.js and passes the data on to the control component with events. The control component could then pass the relevant data on to other components as props. Those components can trigger events that are listened to by the api.store.

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';
import ApiFct from './../utils/api.js';

let ApiStoreObject = {
 newData: {
  "React version": "0.14",
  "Project": "ReFluxSuperAgent",
  "currentDateTime": new Date().toLocaleString()
 },
 listenables: Actions,
 apiInit() { ApiFct.setData(this.newData); },
 apiInitDone() { ApiFct.getData(); },
 apiSetData(data) { ApiFct.setData(data); }
}
const ApiStore = Reflux.createStore(ApiStoreObject);
export default ApiStore;
```

```js
import request from 'superagent';

import Actions from '../flux/Actions';

let uri = 'http://localhost:3500';

module.exports = {
 getData() { request.get(uri + '/routes/getData').end((err, res) => { this.gotData(res.body); }); },
 gotData(data) { Actions.gotData1(data); Actions.gotData2(data); Actions.gotData3(data); },
 setData(data) { request.post('/routes/setData').send(data).end((err, res) => { Actions.apiInitDone(); }) },
};
```

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';
import AddonStore from './Addon.Store';
import MixinStoreObject from './Mixin.Store';

function _GotData(data) { this.data1 = data; BasicStore.trigger('data1'); }

let BasicStoreObject = {
 init() { this.listenTo(AddonStore, this.onAddonTrigger); },
 data1: {},
 listenables: Actions,
 mixins: [MixinStoreObject],
 onGotData1: _GotData,
 onAddonTrigger() { BasicStore.trigger('data2'); },
 getData1() { return this.data1; },
 getData2() { return AddonStore.data2; },
 getData3() { return this.data3; }
}
const BasicStore = Reflux.createStore(BasicStoreObject);
export default BasicStore;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

import BasicStore from './../flux/Basic.Store';

let AppCtrlSty = {
 height: '100%',
 padding: '0 10px 0 0'
}

const getState = () => {
 return {
  Data1: BasicStore.getData1(),
  Data2: BasicStore.getData2(),
  Data3: BasicStore.getData3()
 };
};

class AppCtrlRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
  let data1 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data1, null, 2);
  let data2 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data2, null, 2);
  let data3 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data3, null, 2);
  return (
   <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
    React 1.4 ReFlux with SuperAgent<br/><br/>
    Data1: {data1}<br/><br/>
    Data2: {data2}<br/><br/>
    Data3: {data3}<br/><br/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = getState();
 }

 componentDidMount() { this.unsubscribe = BasicStore.listen(this.storeDidChange.bind(this)); }
 componentWillUnmount() { this.unsubscribe(); }
 storeDidChange(id) {
  switch (id) {
   case 'data1': this.setState({Data1: BasicStore.getData1()}); break;
   case 'data2': this.setState({Data2: BasicStore.getData2()}); break;
   case 'data3': this.setState({Data3: BasicStore.getData3()}); break;
   default: this.setState(getState());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty intense, but there's no guarantee that I'm going to be using React for this.  My goal was to see if there was a Rails-centric solution to this instead.